# Not getting Exact result in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(processed_data_format, columns=["file_name", "innings", "over","ball", "individual ball", "runs","batsman", "wicket_status","bowler_name","fielder_name"])      
a = {'runs':['sum'],'ball':['sum'],'file_name':['unique']}
t = df.groupby('batsman').agg(a)
```

After running this code i am getting result like

```
['Younis Khan', array(['225245', '225247'], dtype=object), 113, 121]
```

But I would like to get the result like

```
['Younis Khan', 2 , 113, 121]
```

instead of array(['225245', '225247'], dtype=object) i need to get count of **file name**

Comment: does `a = {'runs':'sum','ball':'sum','file_name':'unique'}` work?

Comment: @EdChum no it won't ,it will give the same answer

Comment: @EdChum instead of unique, nunique will work